# Performance of jQuery.grep vs. Array.filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

In a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14644693/1047823) it was discussed on how jQuery and native JS would perform against each other.

While of course the vanilla solution performs a lot faster because it does not process the whole array I proposed the usage of `Array.filter` which I was pretty confident would be at least faster than `$.grep`.

Surprisingly after adding it to the test I was taught a lesson: **[Testsuite](http://jsperf.com/grep-vs-pure-js/8)**

[Edgecases](http://jsperf.com/grep-vs-pure-js/7) of course have a different outcome.

Anyone having an idea why `$.grep` is supposed to be over 3 times faster than the native method `Arrray.filter`?

Edit: I modified the test to use the [filter shim from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility) and the results are pretty interesting:

- Chrome: Even MDN shim is faster than the native method, jQuery way ahead
- Firefox: shim a bit slower than native method, jQuery way ahead

and finally a result like i was hoping it to see in

- Internet Explorer: 
  native method is the fastest, then jQuery, shim is slowest (perhaps this is just the result of IEs rather weak JS-engine...)

Answer (score 17):

As found on **[this blog post](http://monkeyandcrow.com/blog/why_javascripts_filter_is_slow/)** (which also does the same kind of tests):

> If you read the documentation for [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), you will see why it's so much slower.
>
> 1. It ignores deleted values and gaps in the array
> 2. It optionally sets the execution context of the predicate function
> 3. It prevents the predicate function from mutating the data

Comment: It's not `Array.filter` implementation, it's just a fallback. `Array.filter` is a native method implemented in the JS engine (C++).

Comment: Still: why is the native filter method obviously slower than jQuery.grep?

Comment: Updated my answer (sorry for the confusion)

Comment: updated my answer as well... the JS-shim performs better than the native method...why???

Comment: In FF18, the native performs slightly better than the shim, but jQuery's still on the top 3 times faster.

Comment: "*It prevents the predicate function from mutating the data*" - I can't find that, neither on MDC nor in the ES spec.

Comment: @Bergi I think that's because a *new* array is created, instead the old one being modified.

Answer (score 8):

[Section 15.4.4.20 of the ECMAScript 5.1 spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.20) defines `Array.prototype.filter(callbackfn, thisArg)` as follows:

> `callbackfn` should be a function that accepts three arguments and
>   returns a value that is coercible to the Boolean value `true` or
>   `false`. `filter` calls `callbackfn` once for each element in the
>   array, in ascending order, and constructs a new array of all the
>   values for which `callbackfn` returns `true`. `callbackfn` is called
>   only for elements of the array which actually exist; it is not called
>   for missing elements of the array.
>
> If a `thisArg` parameter is provided, it will be used as the `this`
>   value for each invocation of `callbackfn`. If it is not provided,
>   `undefined` is used instead.
>
> `callbackfn` is called with three arguments: the value of the element,
>   the index of the element, and the object being traversed.
>
> `filter` does not directly mutate the object on which it is called but
>   the object may be mutated by the calls to `callbackfn`.
>
> The range of elements processed by filter is set before the first call
>   to `callbackfn`. Elements which are appended to the array after the
>   call to filter begins will not be visited by `callbackfn`. If existing
>   elements of the array are changed their value as passed to
>   `callbackfn` will be the value at the time filter visits them;
>   elements that are deleted after the call to filter begins and before
>   being visited are not visited.

That in itself is already a lot of work; a lot of steps that the ECMAScript engine needs to perform.

Then it goes on to say the following:

> When the filter method is called with one or two arguments, the
>   following steps are taken:
>
> Let `O` be the result of calling `ToObject` passing the `this` value as the
>   argument.
>   Let `lenValue` be the result of calling the `[[Get]]` internal
>   method of `O` with the argument `length`.
>   Let `len` be `ToUint32(lenValue)`.
>   If IsCallable(callbackfn) is false, throw a TypeError exception. If
>   thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined. Let A
>   be a new array created as if by the expression new Array() where Array
>   is the standard built-in constructor with that name. Let k be 0. Let
>   to be 0. Repeat, while k < len Let Pk be ToString(k). Let kPresent be
>   the result of calling the [[HasProperty]] internal method of O with
>   argument Pk. If kPresent is true, then Let kValue be the result of
>   calling the [[Get]] internal method of O with argument Pk. Let
>   selected be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of
>   callbackfn with T as the this value and argument list containing
>   kValue, k, and O. If ToBoolean(selected) is true, then Call the
>   [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of A with arguments
>   ToString(to), Property Descriptor {[[Value]]: kValue, [[Writable]]:
>   true, [[Enumerable]]: true, [[Configurable]]: true}, and false.
>   Increase to by 1. Increase k by 1. Return A.
>
> The length property of
>   the filter method is 1.
>
> NOTE The filter function is intentionally generic; it does not require
>   that its this value be an Array object. Therefore it can be
>   transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method. Whether the
>   filter function can be applied successfully to a host object is
>   implementation-dependent.

Some things to note about this algorithm:

- It prevents the predicate function from mutating the data
- It optionally sets the execution context of the predicate function
- It ignores deleted values and gaps in the array

In a lot of cases, none of these things are needed. So, when writing a `filter` method of your own, most of the time you wouldn’t even bother to perform these steps.

Every ES5.1-compliant JavaScript engine must conform to that algorithm, and must thus perform all those steps every time you use `Array#filter`.

It should be no surprise that any custom-written method that only performs a part of those steps will be faster :)

If you write your own `filter` function, chances are it’s not gonna be as complex as the above algorithm. Perhaps you won’t be converting the array to an object at all, as depending on the use case it may not be needed just to filter the array.

Comment: well, in chrome even the js-shim conforming exactly to the ES5-spec is faster than the native function...

Comment: @Christoph It’s not confirming *exactly* to the ES spec. I only glanced at the code for a few seconds and already found something it did differently than how it’s defined in the ES spec. Step 4: “if `IsCallable(callbackfn)` is `false`, throw a `TypeError` exception.” The shim checks this by using `typeof`, which differs from the `IsCallable` algorithm in the spec. The end result may be the same, but it’s an entirely different code path, with a potentially different performance cost.

Answer (score 3):

I found out something interesting. As explained by MarcoK, $.grep is just a simple implementation with a for loop. Filter is slower in most cases, so the implementation must be different. I think i found the answer:

```
function seak (e) { return e === 3; }

var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0], i, before;
array[10000] = 20; // This makes it slow, $.grep now has to iterate 10000 times.
before = new Date();

// Perform natively a couple of times.
for(i=0;i<10000;i++){
    array.filter(seak);
}

document.write('<div>took: ' + (new Date() - before) + '</div>'); // took: 8515 ms (8s)

before = new Date();

// Perform with JQuery a couple of times
for(i=0;i<10000;i++){
    $.grep(array, seak);
}
document.write('<div>took: ' + (new Date() - before) + '</div>'); // took: 51790 ms  (51s)
```

The native 'filter' is much faster in this case. So i think it iterates the properties rather than the array index.

Now lets get back to 'big' problems ;).

Comment: That's in no way an anwer than rather a vague assupmtion. Sure, array indices are just ordinary properties of the array object, but you have to access them trough bracket notation. So it makes no sense to speak of properties or indices - it the same. The only difference is that `Array.prototype.filter` ignores gaps in the array and thus only invokes the filter function 11 times, while `grep` invokes it 10001 times.

Comment: Also i can in no way confirm your times, grep is slow but only up to 50% of the native version ... http://jsperf.com/grep-vs-pure-js/7

Answer (score 2):

Isn't your script wrong?

For `array.filter` you are doing the measurement 1000 times and present it by taken the sum divided by 1000

For `JQuery.grep` you are doing the measurement 1 time and present it by taken the sum divided by 1000.

That would mean your grep is actually 1000 times slower than the value you use for comparison.

Quick test in firefox gives:

```
Machine 1:
average filter - 3.864
average grep - 4.472

Machine2:
average filter - 1.086
average grep - 1.314
```

Quick test in chrome gives:

```
Machine 1:
average filter - 69.095
average grep - 34.077

Machine2:
average filter - 18.726
average grep - 9.163
```

Conclusion in firefox (50.0) is a lot faster for your code path, and filter is about 10-15% faster than jquery.grep.

Chrome is extremely slow for your code path, but grep seems to be 50% faster than array.filter here making it 900% slower than the firefox run.

Answer (score -1):

**TLDR;** Grep is faster by a magnitude... (hint on why [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091065/jquery-grep-vs-native-javascript-filter-function-performance#answer-14091157))

> It looks to me like .filter forces it's this to Object, checks the
>   callback IsCallable and sets this in it as well as checking for
>   existence of property in each iteration whereas .grep assumes and
>   skips these steps, meaning there is slightly less going on.

Here is the script I used for testing:

```js
function test(){
var array = [];
for(var i = 0; i<1000000; i++)
{
array.push(i);
}

var filterResult = []
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
var stime = new Date();
var filter = array.filter(o => o == 99999);
filterResult.push(new Date() - stime);
}

var grepResult = [];
var stime = new Date();
var grep = $.grep(array,function(i,o){
return o == 99999;
});
grepResult.push(new Date() - stime);

$('p').text('average filter - '+(filterResult.reduce((pv,cv)=>{ return pv +cv},0)/1000))
$('div').text('average grep - '+(grepResult.reduce((pv,cv)=>{ return pv + cv},0)/1000))
}
test();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
<div></div>
```

Comment: There was no doubt, that it's faster, the main question however remains unanswered - why? ;)