# Compare two arrays of "strings" to check if they are equal

Tags: javascript, arrays

Good day,

I have two arrays of **strings**. Strings are just numeric dates (eg: "01/01/2016"...).

I would like to know if there is a good/fast way to compare the two arrays and remove the strings from one array, which are not present in second one.

**Example**:

First array: ["01/01/2016","02/02/2015", "03/03/2014"]

Second array: ["01/01/2016", "02/02/2015"]

The string "03/03/2014" should be removed from the first array.

I have tried doing it though for() loops of both array lengths, but it seems to be very slow, because the arrays are big (abt. 1000+) indexes in each, like this:

```
  for (var a = 0; a < oilDateArray.length; a++) {
          for (var b = 0; b < fuelDateArray.length; b++) {
            if (fuelDateArray[b] !== oilDateArray[a]) {
              console.log("fuelDateArray not present: " + fuelDateArray[b]);
            }
          }
        }
```

Is there a specific function/method, which I could use in order to perform the above operation faster?

Thanks in advance and have a nice day!

Comment: I don't think the answer provided there will be any faster. Checking two arrays which are 1000+ strings each by using for() loops is quite slow.

Comment: Can you treat your dataset to use sorted UNIX timestamps instead? I can create an answer using time complexity `O(n)` if you can.

Comment: I get this dates as data from a web service. I can convert it to unix or epoch time, but this would probably be a not very efficient way.

Comment: It will be more efficient than using the `O(n²)` or `O(n*m)` algorithms that are popping here, considering converting to UNIX will take `O(n)` and sorting it will unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
for (var i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++){
    if (secondArray.indexOf(firstArray[i]) == -1){ // indexOf is -1 if not found
        firstArray.splice(i, 1); // Remove 1 value at index i
        i--; // To re-adjust the index value which is 1 less because of the splice
    }
}
```

It may also be a bit slow, you can try with your array : https://jsfiddle.net/tyrsszaw/4

Comment: You need to change `<=` to `<` and adjust `i` because you're reindexing the array when the item is removed.

Comment: You're right @squint , just a mistake

Comment: You still need to adjust `i`. Once you do the `.splice()`, the next index becomes the current one, so the `i++` skips over it. Under the `.splice()` line, add `i--`.

Comment: Oh ok I see what you mean

Comment: @squint this doesn't work. I get the length of the firstArray to be 0. This is the code I used:  for (var g = 0; g < oilDateArray.length; g++){
          if (fuelDateArray.indexOf(oilDateArray[g]) == -1){ // indexOf is -1 if not found
            oilDateArray.splice(g, 1); // Remove 1 value at index g
            g--; // To re-adjust the index value which is 1 less because of the splice
            //console.log("removed: " + oilDateArray[g]);
          }
        }

Comment: @DenissM.: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/tar8v1p1/

Comment: This works perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

with jquery

$(array1).filter(array2);

Comment: This is just wrong. There's no documentation support for passing an array of strings to the `$` function and then using `.filter()` on it.

Comment: it's not, it works...I just tried it......Before giving me negs you should try the code for yourself

Comment: There's no documentation support for passing an array of strings to the `$` function and then using `.filter()` on it. Please read documentation before using (or suggesting) methods. It's really super, duper that it works right now, but it's an unsupported "feature" and can break on any minor point release.

Comment: ...and there's no indication that the OP is using jQuery in the first place, so it would be silly to load it just to do this simple little operation.

Comment: Ok, now I see where you go and you are right for long term purposes....I was just trying to help with a simple solution

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to `Set`:

```
function intersect(arr1, arr2){
    var s = new Set(arr1);
    return arr2.filter(function(el){
        return s.has(el);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i use jquery for array operations and i'll edit one for your need and paste here, i hope this can help you:

```
var arr1 = ["01/01/2016","02/02/2015", "03/03/2014"];
var arr2 = ["01/01/2016", "02/02/2015"];
var diff = [];

jQuery.grep(arr2, function(t) {
        if (jQuery.inArray(t, arr1) == -1) diff.push(t);
});

alert(diff);​ // what was different will be alerted
```

i also found this code on stackoverflow sometime ago.

Update: Here is performance related topic you might be interested

[Performance of jQuery.grep vs. Array.filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647470/performance-of-jquery-grep-vs-array-filter)

tldr;
it says grep is about 3 times faster. So stick with my solution. :)

Comment: Thanks! How is it in terms of performance if comparing big arrays (1000+ items)?

Comment: if you will work with anything related with javascript on client side, it depends on the client actually

Comment: can you explain your case further? Like, if you need to fetch data from api or any connection to database? Or just some plain dates?

Comment: I get these dates from a web service (xml) and then store them inside an array.

Comment: i edited my answer about performance issue.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out. Seems that jQuery is the solution.

Comment: @DenissM.: Loading jQuery to do this operation is like using bazooka to kill a fly.

Comment: Seems, that there is no other solution, which is fast.

Comment: @DenissM.: How could there be no other solution? jQuery is just a library of JS code, so if jQuery can do it, anyone can. In fact, you can get much faster than the provided solution.

Comment: @squint, can you please provide such a solution? I'm a bit new to JS.

Comment: @DenissM.: paulolol's solution should be faster because it requires fewer function calls and uses all native code. You said you tried with `for` loops but it was too slow. If that was too slow, then there's something wrong because `for` loops are the fastest looping construct in JS. Also, MinusFour's solution is probably even faster. The trouble is that your question complains of a performance issue, but you provided no code, so how can anyone know if their solution will actually be better?

Comment: @squint you got a point. i never said that this is the absolute way he should use.Like i said that is what i've been using for my projects. Since he needs a fast working solution this code will fit his needs.

Comment: @squint I have edited my question with the code I have used. This is not working at all now.

Comment: @DenissM.: What isn't working? Your code or the solutions?

Comment: @squint my code. It is too slow.

Comment: You don't have the `console.log()` actually in there, do you?

Comment: @squint I do for debugging.

Comment: @DenissM.: Do you for performance testing? That will really slow things down if it gets called a lot. But put it this way, any solution that mimics what you're currently doing using things like `$.grep` or `.filter()` will be slower because it's the same basic algorithm but with the added overhead of function calls.

Comment: Also, what do you do when a match is found? Do you `break` the inner loop? Are you mutating the original array, or do you create a new array of unique items? There's still important info missing.

Comment: @squint for now I just console log the array element, that wasn't found in the second array. But after I will insert the one found into a new array. So a new array will be created with the correct found dates.

Comment: @DenissM.: If doing you're `console.log()` on every pair that doesn't match, then *of course* it'll be slow. You're trying to optimize code that isn't even the actual application code yet. :P

Comment: But if you're going to `.push()` into a new array for matched items, the do the `.push()` and `break;` the inner loop. No sense continuing the inner loop when you've already found a match.

Comment: @squint ok thanks. I will try out. Thanks a lot for your time!